# Terraform DigitalOcean droplet tags to swarm labels

Tags: terraform

Let's assume we have some DO tags:

```
resource "digitalocean_tag" "foo" {
  name = "foo"
}

resource "digitalocean_tag" "bar" {
  name = "bar"
}
```

And we have configured swarm worker nodes with mentioned tags.

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "swarm_data_worker" {
  name = "swarm-worker-${count.index}"
  tags = [
    "${digitalocean_tag.foo.id}",
    "${digitalocean_tag.bar.id}"
  ]

  // swarm node config stuff

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "docker swarm join --token ${data.external.swarm_join_token.result.worker} ${digitalocean_droplet.swarm_manager.ipv4_address_private}:2377"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to label created swarm node with corresponding resource (droplet) tags.

To label worker nodes we need to run on the swarm `master`:

```
docker node update --label-add foo --label-add bar worker-node
```

How can we automate this with terraform?

Comment: Got the exact same question right now, please update if you find an answer yourself and no one is given here

Comment: You can probably use a 
 [null_resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/null_resource.html) for this. Just set the connection details to one of your manager_nodes and apply the tag based on a map variable.

Comment: @Snowball take a look at the answer, it works for me. If you have progressed with null_resource, please, share it))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Probably not the best way to solve the issue, but until Terraform with full swarm support not released can't find something better.

The main idea is to use pre-installed DO ssh key:

```
variable "public_key_path" {
  description = "DigitalOcean public key"
  default = "~/.ssh/hcmc_swarm/key.pub"
}

variable "do_key_name" {
  description = "Name of the key on Digital Ocean"
  default = "terraform"
}

resource "digitalocean_ssh_key" "default" {
  name = "${var.do_key_name}"
  public_key = "${file(var.public_key_path)}"

}
```

Then we can provision manager:

```
resource "digitalocean_droplet" "swarm_manager" {
  ...
  ssh_keys = ["${digitalocean_ssh_key.default.id}"]

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "docker swarm init --advertise-addr ${digitalocean_droplet.swarm_manager.ipv4_address_private}"
    ]
  }
}
```

And after all we can connect to the swarm_manager via ssh after worker is ready:

```
# Docker swarm labels list

variable "swarm_data_worker__lables" {
  type = "list"
  default = ["type=data-worker"]
}

resource "digitalocean_droplet" "swarm_data_worker" {
  ...
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@${digitalocean_droplet.swarm_manager.ipv4_address_private} docker node update --label-add ${join(" --label-add ", var.swarm_data_worker__lables)} ${self.name}",
    ]
  }
}
```

---

Please, if you know a better approach to solve this issue, don't hesitate to point out via new answer or comment.